# Magento 2.2.4 : Image full path not getting

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento2.2.4

In Magento2.2.4, I load product and get image path. But, It's just display image path like this : `/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg`

I want to get cached image path url. But, It's not get from which collection I load.

How to get it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this code in your block :**

```
protected $_imageHelper;

public function __construct(
    .........................
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
    .........................
)
{
    .........................
    $this->_imageHelper = $imageHelper;
    .........................
}

public function getImageFullPath($product)
{
    return $this->_imageHelper->init($product,'image')->setImageFile($product->getImage())->getUrl();
}
```

**After, Call this function in your phtml :**

```
$imagePath = $block->getImageFullPath($currentProduct);
```

**Clean cache and refresh the page.**